# Cefsharp how to show newly added PrintPreview

Tags: c#, printing, chromium, cefsharp

im curently evaluating Cefsharp for a Projekt. Now i would like to know, how to show the Print Preview(same as in chrome) which you can enable with:

```
var settings = new CefSettings();
settings.EnablePrintPreview();
```

But how can i display that Preview if i want to print a website.
So if i type http://www.google.com/ how can i Print this website with Print Preview Dialog?

I allready tryed:

```
browser.Print()
```

Right click -> Print
And also Played around with chrome://print but nothing is working how i want to.

Comment: Download and test with the CEF Sample application http://opensource.spotify.com/cefbuilds/cef_binary_79.1.36%2Bg90301bd%2Bchromium-79.0.3945.130_windows32_client.tar.bz2 use the command line arg listed at https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/123/add-support-for-print-preview#comment-53064233 this feature is entirely implemented  in CEF.

Comment: Quick test, works fine in `WinForms`, not in `WPF`, this is a bug in `CEF`. You can track progress at https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/123/add-support-for-print-preview#comment-55944942

Comment: @amaitland ok thx for that good to know

Comment: `Print Preview` is only available in `WinForms` see https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/123/add-support-for-print-preview#comment-55952406 for official response. `WPF` uses `OSR`.

Answer (score 1):

bit late but,

```
window.print();
```

also this what i do in my application... and it works fine for me

```
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/imagesloaded@4.1/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var printContents = document.getElementById('main').innerHTML;
        function printDiv() {
            document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
            imagesLoaded(document.body, function() {
                window.print();
            });
        }
    </script>
```

i call printDiv() function when needed and content i need to print is in "main" element

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it.

While initializing CEF pass the settings as a parameter.

```
Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

Answer (score -1):

Imports CefSharp
Imports CefSharp.WinForms

Public Class Form1

```
Private WithEvents browser As ChromiumWebBrowser

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim setBrowser As New CefSettings

    setBrowser.DisableGpuAcceleration()
    setBrowser.AcceptLanguageList = "en-US"
    setBrowser.EnablePrintPreview()

    CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(setBrowser)

    Me.Controls.Add(browser)

    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

 
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77512054/how-to-dynamically-update-parameter-in-power-bi-to-xlsx-automation/77513144#comment136651495_77512054