# How to dynamically update parameter in Power BI to xlsx automation

Tags: sql, powerbi, azure-sql-database, power-automate, azure-automation

I have a Power BI report that I'm trying to export to a XLSX file on Sharepoint each month. The data is being pulled from an Azure SQL database and the query is:

'''
select * From [Reporting].[PremiumBDX_Coaction] ('Pro',2023,**10**)
'''

THe parameter "10" is the @FilterMonth value within our database and is listed as a column within the PowerBI report.

I'm having trouble updating this value automatically so that it updates from month to month. The month value should be the previous month for each monthly report.

[Power Bi Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hadc.png)

Comment: It's unclear what or where you are having trouble. Please share the code you have tried, or the code you want help with. (Update your question).

Comment: @SamNseir I'm trying to find a way to update the parameter within a Power BI report. I'm trying to automate exporting to an xlsx file and one of the parameter's value is the Month's number (which in this case is 10). I'm wanting to automatically have this value updated monthly.....I've added the screen shot of the DAX code above for the column that includes the value I'm wanting to change

Comment: Replace `10` with `MONTH(TODAY()) - 1` ? Or `Date.Month(DateTime.FixedLocalNow()) - 1` for PowerQuery

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@Sam Nseir’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77512054/how-to-dynamically-update-parameter-in-power-bi-to-xlsx-automation/77513144#comment136651495_77512054). The power query worked perfectly:

```
Date.Month(DateTime.FixedLocalNow()) - 1
```